# Update certain property of list of object in react

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to add the `addItem` to the `cartItems` list, but if the `id` is the same as the item that already in the `cartItems`, I don't want to add another object, instead it will add the previous `amountPrice` and `orderAmount` with the new one.

Is there a way for me to achieve that?

```
const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState(cartLocalStorage());

const addToCart = (id, name, image, amountPrice, orderAmount) => {
    const addItem = {
      id: id,
      name: name,
      image: image,
      amountPrice: amountPrice,
      orderAmount: orderAmount,
    };
    setCartItems([...cartItems, addItem]);
  };
};
```

Comment: This part is a little unclear *instead it will add the previous amountPrice and orderAmount with the new one*. Can you elaborate?

Comment: so before the new data got stored in the array, first it will check if the id is already there, which means it won't create another object, but change only the other 2 key properties,  amountPrice and orderAmount. And it won't overwrite it, but it will add the new value which the sum of the old value + new value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
const addToCart = (id, name, image, amountPrice, orderAmount) => {
    if(cartItems.find(i => i.id === id)){
        setCartItems(cartItems.map(item => {
            if(item.id === id){
                item.amountPrice += amountPrice;
                item.orderAmount += orderAmount;
            }
            return item;
        }));
    }else{
        setCartItems([...cartItems, {id, name, image, amountPrice, orderAmount}]);    
    }
}
```

`addToCart` will check if the item is already in `cartItems` by `id` and if so, will add the values of `amountPrice` and `orderAmount` to the corresponding values of the existing element.

If, however, the id is not in `cartItems`, it will add a new element to the array.

Comment: thanks it works, but I have a question. Why did you use ```find()``` not ```filter()``` on this case?

Comment: @BaBi I think using `find` in this context is a bit more intuitive. I could certainly use `filter` and the result would be the same, but `filter` tends to be usually used in situations where you need *multiple* items of an array returned. Since I know there is only one that can match the `id`, `find` appeared more appropriate for readability.

Comment: oh now I understand these concepts, thanks I learned a lot from you.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it and will probably not work but hopefully will set you in the right direction:

```
const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState(cartLocalStorage());

const addToCart = (id, name, image, amountPrice, orderAmount) => {
    const addItem = {
        id: id,
        name: name,
        image: image,
        amountPrice: amountPrice,
        orderAmount: orderAmount,
    };
    const index = cartItems.findIndex(item => item.id === id);
    if (index !== -1) {
        cartItems[index] = {...cartItems[index], ...addItem};
        setCartItems(cartItems);
    } else {
        setCartItems([...cartItems, addItem]);
    }
};
```

Cheers